# pandas: capitalize all or the first n words in the column names

Tags: python, pandas, string, capitalize

I am trying to find how to capitalize the first and second word of column header.

Example:

`check match` ==> `Check Match`

`date found` ==> `Date Found`

Thank you

Comment: Please include some sample data to make it clear what you want here.

Answer (score 6):

##### capitalize all words

If you want to capitalize all words, use:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.title()
```

or:

```
df.rename(columns=str.title, inplace=True)
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['example', 'longer example', 'quite longer example'])
```

output headers:

```
['Example', 'Longer Example', 'Quite Longer Example']
```

##### capitalize only the first n words

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r'(\w+)', lambda x: x.group().capitalize(),
                                    n=2, regex=True)
```

example:

```
['Example', 'Longer Example', 'Quite Longer example']
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the much needed detail example

Answer (score 1):

```
# if your data frame is `df`, then:
df.columns = [s.capitalize() for s in df.columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try?

```
df.columns=df.columns.str.title()
```